# React multiple events attachment as jsx expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have a query about JSX syntax support, will it be possible to give jsx expressions inside js object?

I have a Button component like this,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default function ButtonComponent(props){

    return (
        <button id={props.id} type="button" onClick={props.onClick} onMouseDown={props.onMouseDown} >
        {props.value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

It will be used in some other component like bellow,

```
<ButtonComponent id="first" value="First" onClick={this.clickHandler} onMouseDown={this.mouseDownHandler}/>
```

As you can observe there is an array pattern getting created for events. It might grow with onMouseOver, onMouseUp etc.. events.

So I was just wondering if I could pass all the events as one object and attach them with spread operator?

Like I will modify the ButtonComponent as,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default function ButtonComponent(props){

    return (
        <button id={props.id} type="button" {...props.events} >
        {props.value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

And use this component like below,

```
<ButtonClass id="first" value="First" 
events={{onClick:{this.clickHandler}, onMouseDown:{this.mouseDownHandler}, onMouseOver:{this.mouseOverHandler}}}/>
```

But it throws error saying invalid syntax.

If I update the events object like below, it passes the syntax validation but events does not execute.

```
<ButtonClass id="first" value="First" 
events={{onClick:(this.clickHandler), onMouseDown:(this.mouseDownHandler), onMouseOver:(this.mouseOverHandler)}}/>
```

Is there and way to achieve this pattern with out attaching all the events in the ButtonComponent?

Sorry for the long post..

Comment: You could also use a combination of rest/spread syntax if that fits your use case, e.g. `const ButtonComponent = ({ value, ...rest }) => <button type="button" {...rest}>{value}</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define event listeners like an object and pass it to component with rest-spread operator. For example

```
const EVENTS = {
    onMouseOver: () => console.log("mouseover"),
    onMouseOut: () => console.log("mouseout"),
    onClick: () => console.log("click"),
    ...
}

class MyCoolComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <button {...this.props.events}>{this.props.children}</button>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyCoolComponent events={EVENTS}>Some children</MyCoolComponent>,
    document.body
)
```

However, this is not very convenient, because you always can mistype the event prop name (e.g. `onCLick` or something) and get the error in runtime. But it is possible :)